# Using Linq (Select, Where...) On asynchronous list

Tags: list, linq, asp.net-core, asynchronous, task

I have an asynchronous list (toListAsync) and I need to perform a linq select statement on it but it doesn't work because Task does not contain a definition for select.
What can I do?

```cs
public async Task<List<FilesTable>> List()
{
    using (var ctx = Configuration.OpenContext(false))
    {
        return await ctx.FilesTables.Include(e => e.Subsection).ToListAsync();
    }
}

// The above is in the first file(FilesTable.cs),
// the below in a different file(file_apis.cs)
public async Task<List<FilesModel>> GetFiles()
{
    return await new FilesTable().List().Select(e => (FilesModel)e).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `using System.Linq;` namespace.

Then you can do this:

```
(await yourMethod.ToListAsync()).Select(a => new { });
```

You should add parenthesis before `await` keyword and after `ToListAsync()` method

Answer (score 0):

From performance PoV it is better to use filters first, then at the end use `ToListAsync`, so you can use:

```cs
MyList.Where(x => ...).Select(x => ...).ToListAsync();
```

Otherwise you will be loading unnecessary amount of data to the memory, and this will reduce the performance depending on the amount of data. But if you do filter before `ToList` only the required data will be loaded.

#### [Update]

With reference to your code, you can a new method to the `FilesTable.cs` that will do filter and return the desired list:

```cs
public async Task<List<FilesModel>> ListFiles()
{
    using(var cts = Configuration.OpenContext(false))
    {
        return await ctx.FilesTables.Include(e => e.Subsection).Select(e => (FilesModel)e).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to convert from one class to another and for that I need the select, 

```
            return await new FilesTable().List().Select(a=>(FilesModel)a).ToList();```

Comment: I made a user defined conversion from filesmodel to filestable and vice versa and for the conversion to work in list I have to use the Select

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to the questions?

Comment: public async Task<List<FilesTable>> List()
        {
            using (var ctx = Configuration.OpenContext(false))
            {
                return await ctx.FilesTables.Include(e => e.Subsection).ToListAsync();
            }
        }
The above is in the first file(FilesTable.cs), the below in a different file(file_apis.cs)

 public async Task<List<FilesModel>> GetFiles() 
        {
            return await new FilesTable().List().Select(e =>( FilesModel)e).ToList();
        }

Comment: Just add a new method to the `FilesTable.cs` that will do the filter and return new model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or brekets for waiting the iteration end for doing the select, or you can use IAsyncEnumerable

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<FilesTable> List()
{
    using (var ctx = Configuration.OpenContext(false))
    {
        return ctx.FilesTables.Include(e => e.Subsection).AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }
}

public async IAsyncEnumerable<FilesModel> GetFiles()
{
     await foreach(var value in new FilesTable().List())
     {
         yield return value;
     }
}

// or using that nuget package System.Linq.Async NuGet package
public async Task<List<FilesModel>> GetFiles()
{
    return await new FilesTable().List().ToListAsync();
}
```